# Force More Specific Subclass Type with Generics in Kotlin

Tags: java, generics, kotlin

I am working on a library that has a few interfaces that are related to each other.

Main example is `ViewModel<M: Model, W: Widget>`. Then we have an interface for Model and interface for Widget.

The widget interface has a method that takes in a ViewModel object and then uses it to configure itself.

`abstract fun configure(viewModel: ViewModel<M: Model, W: Widget>)`

I am looking for a way to make that method require the subclass implementation of ViewModel, instead of just the interface.

So a ContainerWidget would need this method: `fun configure(viewModel: ContainerViewModel)`

The library I am emulating is using Swift and does this with their associated type keyword, which says you can tell us the type later.

Does anyone know an option like that for Kotlin?

Thanks a lot for the help.

```
abstract class WLViewModel<DataModel : WLDataModel, WidgetType : WLWidget>(val dataModel: DataModel) {
    abstract fun configure(view: WidgetType)
}

interface WLWidget {
    var viewModel: WLViewModel<WLDataModel, WLWidget> 

    fun <M, O : WLDataModel, T : WLWidget> configure(viewModel: M) where M : WLViewModel<O, T>
}

interface WLDataModel

fun WLWidget.create(viewModel: WLViewModel<WLDataModel, WLWidget>) {
    configure(viewModel)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a good way, I'm afraid.

The traditional Java approach fudges it by using recursive type parameters.  You could give your `WLWidget` interface a type parameter of the actual subclass, like `WLWidget<T : WLWidget<T>>`, and then make all the knock-on changes.  But that's ugly and doesn't handle all cases.  ([See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54304896/recursive-type-parameters-in-kotlin) [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44466716/is-it-possible-to-create-a-recursive-function-type-in-kotlin) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44408683/higher-order-or-recursive-generic-type-parameters-in-kotlin) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565043/how-to-specify-own-type-as-return-type-in-kotlin) for more info.)

There have been [discussions](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/self-types/371) about adding self types to Kotlin, which would probably be a better match for your case, but they're not here yet.

Comment: I was able to accomplish it with Java. Currently planning on having interface/base abstract class setup in Java and then use Kotlin for all implementations.

I do need to read up on any risks this could cause, but it is currently working now and enforcing correct subclass/implementor type at compile time.